# Why do the notifications work in the emulator but not on a real Android device for a medicament alarm clock app?

Tags: java, android

Notifications from alarm works fine in emulator, but doesn't work in real device

Hello everyone! My medicaments alarm clock program works well on the emulator, does not give out any errors, the notification comes in, but when I transfer the application to a real device through the APK file, the notifications do not work, I ask for help.
My Alarm receiver

```
public final class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = AlarmReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "alarm_channel";

    private static final String BUNDLE_EXTRA = "bundle_extra";
    private static final String ALARM_KEY = "alarm_key";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.e(TAG, "onReceive: start" );
        final Alarm alarm = intent.getBundleExtra(BUNDLE_EXTRA).getParcelable(ALARM_KEY);
        if(alarm == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Alarm is null", new NullPointerException());
            return;
        }

        final int id = alarm.notificationId();

        final NotificationManager manager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        createNotificationChannel(context);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_white_24dp)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.blue))
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(alarm.getLabel())
                .setTicker(alarm.getLabel())
                .setVibrate(new long[] {1000,500,1000,500,1000,500})
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM))
                .setContentIntent(launchAlarmLandingPage(context, alarm))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(123, builder.build());

    }

    public static void setReminderAlarm(Context context, Alarm alarm) {
        Log.e(TAG, "setReminderAlarm: start" );

        //Check whether the alarm is set to run on any days
        if(!AlarmUtils.isAlarmActive(alarm)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "setReminderAlarm: is Inactive" );
            //If alarm not set to run on any days, cancel any existing notifications for this alarm
            cancelReminderAlarm(context, alarm);
            return;
        }

        final Calendar nextAlarmTime = getTimeForNextAlarm(alarm);
        alarm.setTime(nextAlarmTime.getTimeInMillis());

        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(ALARM_KEY, alarm);
        intent.putExtra(BUNDLE_EXTRA, bundle);

        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                alarm.notificationId(),
                intent,
                FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );

        ScheduleAlarm.with(context).schedule(alarm, pIntent);
    }

    public static void setReminderAlarms(Context context, List<Alarm> alarms) {
        for(Alarm alarm : alarms) {
            setReminderAlarm(context, alarm);
        }
    }

    private static Calendar getTimeForNextAlarm(Alarm alarm) {

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(alarm.getTime());

        final long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final int startIndex = getStartIndexFromTime(calendar);

        int count = 0;
        boolean isAlarmSetForDay;

        final SparseBooleanArray daysArray = alarm.getDays();

        do {
            final int index = (startIndex + count) % 7;
            isAlarmSetForDay =
                    daysArray.valueAt(index) && (calendar.getTimeInMillis() > currentTime);
            if(!isAlarmSetForDay) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                count++;
            }
        } while(!isAlarmSetForDay && count < 7);

        return calendar;

    }

    public static void cancelReminderAlarm(Context context, Alarm alarm) {

        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                alarm.notificationId(),
                intent,
                FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );

        final AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(pIntent);
    }

    private static int getStartIndexFromTime(Calendar c) {

        final int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        int startIndex = 0;
        switch (dayOfWeek) {
            case Calendar.MONDAY:
                startIndex = 0;
                break;
            case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                startIndex = 1;
                break;
            case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                startIndex = 2;
                break;
            case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                startIndex = 3;
                break;
            case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                startIndex = 4;
                break;
            case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                startIndex = 5;
                break;
            case Calendar.SUNDAY:
                startIndex = 6;
                break;
        }

        return startIndex;

    }

    private static void createNotificationChannel(Context ctx) {
        if(SDK_INT < O) return;

        final NotificationManager mgr = ctx.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        if(mgr == null) return;

        final String name = ctx.getString(R.string.channel_name);
        if(mgr.getNotificationChannel(name) == null) {
            final NotificationChannel channel =
                    new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.enableVibration(true);
            channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[] {1000,500,1000,500,1000,500});
            channel.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM),null);
            channel.setBypassDnd(true);
            mgr.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    private static PendingIntent launchAlarmLandingPage(Context ctx, Alarm alarm) {
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(
                ctx, alarm.notificationId(), launchIntent(ctx), FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
    }

    private static class ScheduleAlarm {
        private static final String TAG = "ScheduleAlarm";

        @NonNull private final Context ctx;
        @NonNull private final AlarmManager am;

        private ScheduleAlarm(@NonNull AlarmManager am, @NonNull Context ctx) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ScheduleAlarm: constructor" );
            this.am = am;
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        static ScheduleAlarm with(Context context) {
            Log.e(TAG, "with: contect" );
            final AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            if(am == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("AlarmManager is null");
            }
            return new ScheduleAlarm(am, context);
        }

        void schedule(Alarm alarm, PendingIntent pi) {
            if(SDK_INT > LOLLIPOP) {
                Log.e(TAG, "schedule: now"+alarm.getTime() );
                am.setAlarmClock(new AlarmClockInfo(alarm.getTime(), launchAlarmLandingPage(ctx, alarm)), pi);
            } else if(SDK_INT > KITKAT) {
                am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm.getTime(), pi);
            } else {
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm.getTime(), pi);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

My manifest

```
 <receiver android:name=".alarm.service.AlarmReceiver"
            android:process=":remote"/>`
```

My permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.androidtutorialpoint.mymapsappsdirection.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```